# Flutter 3.10.0 popping fails with GoRouter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

I am using the `GoRouter` with the lates `3.10.0` release but after upgrade the flutter version my app fails with this `error`:

> _AssertionError ('package:go_router/src/delegate.dart': Failed assertion: line 158 pos 12: 'match != null': is not true.)

This is what I do:

```
     if (mounted) {
        if (context.canPop()) {
          context.pop();  // <- this line fails 
        }
        context.pushReplacement('/projects/localizeIt');
      }
```

Before the upgrade everything was working just fine. Any updates I need adjust to that I missed? Let me know if you need any more info.